# Create static method with same name as extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, static-methods

I have created an extension method called `IsOccluded`. I attempted to create a static method within the same code file with the same name and parameters just not an extension:

```
public static bool IsOccluded(Vector2 point, Matrix world) { }
public static bool IsOccluded(this Vector2 point, Matrix world) { }
```

However, since the parameters are essentially the same in the compiler's eyes, this is not allowed. This makes it seem odd to me since they are called differently:

```
Vector2 position;
Matrix world;
Rendering2D.IsOccluded(position, world);
position.IsOccluded(world);
```

I have changed the name of the non-extension method to `IsPointOccluded` to remove the error, plus it reads a little cleaner anyways. But this leads me to my question:

---

They appear to be two different methods with two different signatures, so why does the compiler complain?

I know that the following cannot compile because the signatures are exactly the same:

```
public void X(int y, double j) { }
public void X(int a, double z) { }
```

Am I missing a core concept on this topic?

Comment: You can use an extension method like a regular method. `Rendering2D.IsOccluded(position, world);` is valid for both forms. There is no need to create two methods.

Comment: @ja72 But why would you call the extension method off of a container file such as `Extensions.MyExtension`; wouldn't it make more sense to call it off of the proper type instead?

Comment: Extension just add an extra way to call a static method. It doesn't change anything else.

Comment: PS. Methods and properties that start with the word `Is...` should return `bool`. It is just common sense since they answer a question.

Comment: So it looks like I missed the fundamental fact that creating the method as an extension is just adding an additional way to call it for simplicity. Thank you both for taking the time to respond and at least clear up why it wouldn't work the way I expected. Also, @ja72 I failed to type that into my post but they do in fact return `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not

> essentially the same

they ARE the same.

Both are static methods with the same parameters that have the same type and both are called the same exact way except the one with `this` add an extra way to call.

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void IsOccluded(this Vector2 point, Matrix world) { }
}
```

This method is static AND extension which mean 1 extra way to call it.
First the usual way :

```
Foo.IsOccluded(new Vector2(), new Matrix);
```

Second way is by using what the extension shortcut that is offered to the compiler

```
new Vector2().IsOccluded(new Matrix);
```

Comment: @PerpetualJ, also realize, if analyzing at the C# language level doesn't do it for you, the goal of C# is to build .NET classes. In .NET, an "extension method" is simply a method with the ExtensionAttribute, which wouldn't make one method sufficiently different than another. C# has rules around both creating and calling such methods.

Answer (score 2):

Only one method is needed and it can be used as an extension or a regular method:

Consider the following valid code:

```
public static class Rendering3D
{
    public static bool IsOccluded(this Vector2 point, Matrix world) { }
}

static void Main()
{
    Matrix world = ...
    Vector2 point = ...
    if( point.IsOccluded(world) )
    {
    }
    if( Rendering3D.IsOccluded(point, world) )
    {
    }
}
```